# How to resolve "not authorized for query on db.users" Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, mongoid4

I've created a new Rails app using Rails 4 and Mongoid 4. I'm getting this error `"not authorized for query on mydb.users"` when I run my test:

```
RSpec.describe User, type: :model do

    it "is invalid without a name" do
        user = User.new(name: nil)
        user.valid?
        expect(user).to be_invalid
    end
    ...

end
```

At first I thought this was an authorisation issue with Mongoid and MongoDB, but I can access mongoldb/db/collection without authenticate in the console without trouble.

Because I'm new to Rspec tests, I'm not sure the problem is with my test, mongoid or mongodb.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB provide access on database level and it store on database level also. You need to provide access on this database like :
`use mydb;
    db.createUser(
     {
     user: "accountUser",
     pwd: "password",
     roles: [ "readWrite", "dbAdmin" ]
     }
   )`